# Getting SQL under Source Control with Visual Studio Database Projects

Tags: sql, visual-studio, version-control

Just trying to see if it is reliable enough to import Database into Visual Studio and then push it under Source Control, later to use Visual Studio to generate change scripts and for deployment as well?

I've been talking with my work colleagues and they said that it is not reliable enough to use Visual Studio for generating change scripts as it is not able to generate the correct update/change scripts.

They have been building a tool to compare schemas and to load database objects into one xml file which will be used as the baseline and anytime a change required, dev should edit the xml file manually and then run cmd command to generate the SQL change script.

From my perspective I see it is much easier to use VS for editing and deploying changes as it has intellisense and all the fancy IDE features.

Comment: SSDT is very good at generating change scripts for schema but it is quite conservative. By default it won't allow you to change `NULL`able columns to `NOT NULL` if there's data in the table (because the schema upgrade can fail if there's a null value in there). It also doesn't handle data particularly well (it has a data diff but relies on primary keys representing the same thing - so you if you have surrogate keys then it doesn't work so well). It also has limited refactoring support. (e.g. rename a column => cascade that change to the foreign keys and indexes on that column). TL;DR Use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database projects in visual studio are great. We've been using it for a while and never had problems. Unless you use something like EF code first you MUST keep your db objects under source control just the same way you keep your code!

Comment: Hi Zdravko, thanks for your prompt response! have you come to a moment where VS will generate unnecessary or not needed scrips that you might not consider when deploying? or it could actually miss with the existing schema! I know that there has to be human intervention to review the script before deployment but just as in general.